# Ubuntu 20.04 Crashes

Tags: 20.04, gui, crash

I recently bought a pc. After installing ubuntu it constantly crashes after about 1 hour.
The screen remains frozen. Sometimes pc doesn't restart or shutdown or start. Mainly the gui remains stuck. Then the pc needs to hard reset. I clean reinstalled Ubuntu again but the problem remains the same. During the reinstallation,the installer also crashed once.

I am using an old monitor with hdmi to vga converter.

`Installation Info:`

```
I used GPT partition scheme to install ubuntu by enabling uefi from the bios.
```

My PC Config:
Processor: Ryzen 3 3200G
Mobo: MSI A320M pro max
Ram: 16 GB (2x8GB Gskill Ripjaws 2400 MHZ)
SSD: 120 GB
HDD: 500 GB(This is a old HDD)
and an old asus optical drive from my previous Desktop.

`free -h:`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           13Gi       1.5Gi        10Gi        46Mi       1.4Gi        11Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

`sysctl vm.swappiness`

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

`swapon -s`

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                file       2097148 0        -2
```

`sudo lshw -C memory`

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 2.80
       date: 12/07/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: f
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: F4-2400C15-8GVR
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: F4-2400C15-8GVR
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 11
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 12
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 13
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`

```
2.80
```

`sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`

```
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop1: detected capacity change from 0 to 133320
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop2: detected capacity change from 0 to 66152
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop3: detected capacity change from 0 to 113536
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop4: detected capacity change from 0 to 104360
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Finished Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop5: detected capacity change from 0 to 66144
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 12883.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revis>
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, rev>
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 344 (plymouthd).
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password>
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth>
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 5>
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for core18, revision 2128.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 12704.
Sep 08 17:08:10 my-pc systemd[1]: plymouth-start.service: Main process exited, >
Sep 08 17:08:10 my-pc systemd[1]: plymouth-start.service: Failed with result 's>
Sep 08 17:08:17 my-pc systemd[1]: Caught <ABRT>, dumped core as pid 353.
Sep 08 17:08:17 my-pc systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
lines 979-1001/1001 (END)
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop1: detected capacity change from 0 to 133320
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop2: detected capacity change from 0 to 66152
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop3: detected capacity change from 0 to 113536
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop4: detected capacity change from 0 to 104360
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Finished Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop5: detected capacity change from 0 to 66144
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 12883.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 72.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1515.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 344 (plymouthd).
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 547.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for core18, revision 2128.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 12704.
Sep 08 17:08:10 my-pc systemd[1]: plymouth-start.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Sep 08 17:08:10 my-pc systemd[1]: plymouth-start.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Sep 08 17:08:17 my-pc systemd[1]: Caught <ABRT>, dumped core as pid 353.
Sep 08 17:08:17 my-pc systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 979-1001/1001 (END)
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop1: detected capacity change from 0 to 133320
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop2: detected capacity change from 0 to 66152
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop3: detected capacity change from 0 to 113536
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop4: detected capacity change from 0 to 104360
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Finished Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc kernel: loop5: detected capacity change from 0 to 66144
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 12883.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 72.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1515.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 344 (plymouthd).
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 547.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for core18, revision 2128.
Sep 08 17:08:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 12704.
Sep 08 17:08:10 my-pc systemd[1]: plymouth-start.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Sep 08 17:08:10 my-pc systemd[1]: plymouth-start.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Sep 08 17:08:17 my-pc systemd[1]: Caught <ABRT>, dumped core as pid 353.
Sep 08 17:08:17 my-pc systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
```

`ls -al /var/crash`

```
total 48192
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Sep  8 17:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root         4096 Aug 19 16:47 ..
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie  6246907 Sep  8 17:23 _usr_bin_gedit.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 17:23 _usr_bin_gedit.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 17:23 _usr_bin_gedit.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie 36534711 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 05:05 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie   247402 Sep  8 04:47 _usr_bin_gnome-terminal.wrapper.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 04:47 _usr_bin_gnome-terminal.wrapper.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 04:47 _usr_bin_gnome-terminal.wrapper.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie   942295 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_gnome-session-binary.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_gnome-session-binary.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 05:05 _usr_libexec_gnome-session-binary.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie  2468649 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_gsd-media-keys.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_gsd-media-keys.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 05:05 _usr_libexec_gsd-media-keys.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie   570130 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_gvfsd-trash.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_gvfsd-trash.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 05:05 _usr_libexec_gvfsd-trash.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie  2026730 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   247580 Sep  8 04:51 _usr_sbin_update-mime.0.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 Sep  8 04:51 _usr_sbin_update-mime.0.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 04:51 _usr_sbin_update-mime.0.uploaded
```

Comment: are you able to open a terminal and check `dmesg` log?

Comment: You may want to check the `/var/log/syslog` file to see if there are any errors reported around the time of the crash. These may look like temperature warnings, hardware disconnections, and/or kernel panics. If you could [edit] your question to include some of these messages, it might be possible to receive some specific support to resolve the issue 

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.
  
Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.
  
You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.

Comment: Can not open terminal @admin

Comment: Edited @heynnema

Comment: When it crashes nothing works except hard reset and REISUB @admin

Comment: Sometimes REISUB also does not work @admin

Comment: I have added journalctl to the post taken after a crash but didn't understand it much @waltinator

Comment: Are you booted to your SSD, or to a USB flash drive? What brand SSD? What video card and driver version? Show me `ls -al /var/crash`. Your memory looks strange. Has this system ever worked properly? Is your CPU or RAM overclocked? Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: Your RAM isn't on the compatible list as seen on https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/A320M-A-PRO-MAX/#support-mem-18. Report back after running `memtest`.

Comment: I am booted to my ssd. 
SSD: Transcend 820s 120gb m.2

Comment: ls -al /var/crash is added to the post @heynnema

Comment: This is a new system bought just 2 days ago. It has never worked properly after installing ubuntu 20.04.03
XMP profile is enabled but it didn't work even before i enabled xmp profile @heynnema

Comment: Disable XMP before running `memtest`.

Comment: Test Failed due to too many errors.
Test Passed : 3/4
@heynnema

Comment: RAM Info : 2x8GB Gskill Ripjaws 2400 MHZ @heynnema

Comment: Remove 1 DIMM and rerun `memtest`. Report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of crashing...

ls -al /var/crash

```
total 48192
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Sep  8 17:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root         4096 Aug 19 16:47 ..
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie  6246907 Sep  8 17:23 _usr_bin_gedit.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 17:23 _usr_bin_gedit.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 17:23 _usr_bin_gedit.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie 36534711 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 05:05 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie   247402 Sep  8 04:47 _usr_bin_gnome-terminal.wrapper.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 04:47 _usr_bin_gnome-terminal.wrapper.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 04:47 _usr_bin_gnome-terminal.wrapper.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie   942295 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_gnome-session-binary.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_gnome-session-binary.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 05:05 _usr_libexec_gnome-session-binary.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie  2468649 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_gsd-media-keys.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_gsd-media-keys.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 05:05 _usr_libexec_gsd-media-keys.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie   570130 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_gvfsd-trash.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_gvfsd-trash.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 05:05 _usr_libexec_gvfsd-trash.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 sdam1n   whoopsie  2026730 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 sdam1n   whoopsie        0 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 05:04 _usr_libexec_xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   247580 Sep  8 04:51 _usr_sbin_update-mime.0.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 Sep  8 04:51 _usr_sbin_update-mime.0.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Sep  8 04:51 _usr_sbin_update-mime.0.uploaded
```

Your memory looks strange.

Ryzen processors can have RAM compatibility issues.

```
Processor: Ryzen 3 3200G
Mobo: MSI A320M pro max
Ram: 16 GB (2x8GB Gskill Ripjaws 2400 MHZ)
product: F4-2400C15-8GVR
```

Your BIOS is current at 2.80.

Your RAM isn't on the compatible list as seen on https://msi.com/Motherboard/support/A320M-A-PRO-MAX/#support-mem-18.

`free -h` reports only 13G out of 16G installed.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

`memtest` fails. Remove one 8G DIMM and rerun `memtest`. Then test the other one. Possible bad motherboard, or bad (or not compatible) DIMM.

**Update #2:**

One DIMM passed `memtest`. One DIMM failed `memtest`. Will try to get a warranty replacement and re-run `memtest`.

Comment: One of the ram failed the test but the other passed. @heynnema

Comment: so one of the ram is bad then.. @heynnema

Comment: or is it the compatibility issue? @heynnema

Comment: @sdam1n Could be either. Since the RAM is probably under warranty, just get them to replace it, then re-run memtest. Glad we found the problem!

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot for helping :) @heynnema

Comment: @sdam1n You're more than welcome! Make sure that the good DIMM also passes `memtest` in the other DIMM slot.